# Pass NSMutableArray from Delegate file to UITableView from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, delegates, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I do the following:

**myAppDelegate file**

### I'm parsing an xml file and set its content to  `NSMutableArray * catalogue`, this way:

```
NSMutableArray * catalogue;
    NSMutableDictionary * item;

    NSString * currentElement;
    NSMutableString *currentName, *currentUrl;
```

---

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"catalog"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentName forKey:@"name"];
        [item setObject:currentUrl forKey:@"url"];
        [catalogue addObject:[item copy]];
    }
    }
```

**myUiViewController class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    nameCatalog = [myAudiAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].catalogue;
    NSLog(@"noul sir format %@", nameCatalog);

}
```

This is what my `nameCatalog` looks like:

```
 {
    name = "Audi TT Coup\U00e9";
    url = "http://host_server/uploads/modeles_pdf/43_TT_Coupe_TT_Roadster_Catalogue_Tarifs_20110428.pdf";
},
    {
    name = "Audi TT Roadster";
    url = "http://host_server/uploads/modeles_pdf/42_TT_Coupe_TT_Roadster_Catalogue_Tarifs_20110428.pdf";
}
```

What I don't know is...how do I get the name value from there to put it in a tableView?

This is my method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.text = [nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

But I get the following error:
T`erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized`

How should I acces `nameCatalog`?Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is the solution for you problem...

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

**nameCatalog** is your NSMutableArray. **[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]** returns a NSMutableDictionary. And you have to get the value by using valueForKey from that.

Comment: Here nameCatalog is a dictionary of dictionary, is not an array. so how you can call objectAtIndex on NSDictionary?

Comment: In code, George has clearly mentioned NSMutableArray *catalogue; and as you follow the code, you shall come to know the architecture of it.

Comment: One thing to add, the cell.text property is deprecated since 3.0?, you should use cell.textLabel.text instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
int index = indexPath.row;
NSString* name = [[nameCatalog objectForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:index];
NSString* URL = [[nameCatalog objectForKey:@"url"]objectAtIndex:index];
```

if nameCatalog is an array of dictionary, then

```
int index = indexPath.row;
NSString* name = [[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString* URL = [[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Answer (score 3):

use this one

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[catalogue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
```